# Why can't I use a ScrollView within a ColumnLayout?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ScrollView around a ListView. But when I put this in a ColumnLayout, the ListView disappears.

My actual code is larger and more complicated, but I've reduced the problem down to this small example.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: theModel
        ListElement { display: "one" }
        ListElement { display: "two" }
        ListElement { display: "three" }
        ListElement { display: "four" }
        ListElement { display: "five" }
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        ScrollView
        {
            width: 150
            height: 150
            clip: true
            ListView {
                model: theModel
                anchors.fill: parent
                delegate: Column {
                    TextField {
                        text: display
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "black"
            width: 100
            height: 30
        }
    }
}
```

Without the ColumnLayout and the Rectangle, I get a scrollable window showing part of the ListView as expected. But with them included, there is no sign of the ListView apart from some blank space above the rectangle.

Comment: I would rather define the size (either width / height or somehow else) for that ColumnLayout and then make nested items to fit. Right now we have ColumnLayout with no size and neither it is positioned in that Window.

Comment: Good point @alexander-v . I'm gradually getting the hang of this! I used anchors.fill: parent in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

A [Qt Quick Layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-index.html) resize all its children items (e.g. `ColumnLayout` resizes children's height, `RowLayout` resizes children's width), so you should use `Layout` [attached property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) to indicate how to layout them, rather than setting the sizes. e.g.

```
ScrollView {
    Layout.maximumHeight: 150 // height will be updated according to these layout properties

    width: 150
    clip: true
    ListView {
        model: theModel
        anchors.fill: parent
        delegate: Column {
            TextField {
                text: display
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me realize I didn't want a Layout at all, I wanted a Positioner. (ie a Column instead of a Column Layout). See my answer below.

Comment: @NigelSharp Your comment seems to contradict the title of your publication: *I didn't want a Layout at all* - *Why can't I use a ScrollView within a Column- **Layout**?*

Answer (score 0):

A Layout changes the sizes and positions of its children. But as I was specifying the sizes of the children I only wanted to change the positions. A Positioner is used for this (specifically, a Column instead of a ColumnLayout). Additionally I had not set the size of the parent Layout (/Positioner), so I now do this with anchors.fill: parent.

```
    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ScrollView
        {
            width: 150
            height: 150
            clip: true
            ListView {
                model: theModel
                anchors.fill: parent
                delegate: Column {
                    TextField {
                        text: display
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "black"
            width: 100
            height: 30
        }
    }
```

Thanks to other's comment and answer for helping me realize this!

Comment: There're some principle when choosing Positioner or Layout, but the most important one is, if a container's size is specified (by it self or its parent), you should consider a Layout, otherwise, if  a container's size is computed from its children, a Positioner will fit in most cases.

Comment: The `anchors.fill` doesn't make much sense here, unless you want the `Column` to take more space than what's needed by its children. Without it it will implicitely have a width of 150 (the max width of its children) and a height of 180 (the sum of the height of its children.